# site-onload-gif within php

Tags: javascript, php, onload

problem is, that the website is loading like for about 20 second or longer (user-problems preprogrammed)
my solution was to load a pre-site where the user sees a loading screen.
i did this with this html-site but i want to do the same in php.
the test-page is http://kater.selfhost.me/test/

Source Code:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" > 
<head runat="server"> 
<title></title> 
<script type="text/javascript">
        window.onload = function() {
            document.getElementById("siteLoader").style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById("container").style.display = "block";
        }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container" style="display:none">
<div id="body">
<iframe src="http://kater.selfhost.me/stats/skins.php" frameborder="0" height="2000px" width="1024px"></iframe>
</div>
</div>
<div id='siteLoader'> 
<div id='siteDetailLoader'> 
<img src='ajax_loader.gif' border='0'> 
Please wait while the page loads...<br /> <br /> 
</div> 
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

i tried some workarounds, but after searching & testing for about three hours i give up... 
thanks in advance for any help provided! :-D

Comment: You can't make a pre-load with backend (such as PHP, Java, etc..) as it's running at server side, not at the client's browser. So the PHP's content is sent to brownser at once... you can't print partially a PHP response just with pure PHP. Also, this way is fine to accomplish what you want.

Comment: Try combining all the country flags into a single file. How do you determine the country anyway? If you query a remote service on every request that will also slow down your site

Comment: @onetrickpony how do you mean this with all in one file? please describe how to gain the single image out of this big image please. i use a script i found for reading a small database vs the transmitted ip.

Comment: @Wagner my main goal is to get rid of the iframe, due to sizing issues

Comment: So you can load by ajax, is much better, see my answer

Comment: @Kater: see for example: http://flag-sprites.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding what I alredy said at your question commentary, I made a code loading this content via AJAX:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    $( document ).ready(function() {
        //Load content
        loadAjaxContent();
    });

    function loadAjaxContent()
    {

         //VERY IMPORTANT: the URL domain MUST HAVE be the same as your request
         //that's why I'm not writting the full http://kater.selfhost.me/stats/skins.php
        $.ajax({
          url: "/stats/skins.php"
        }).done(function(data) {
            //remove loader
          $("#siteLoader").hide();

            //put PHP content
            $("#ajaxContent").html(data);
        });
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="body">

    <div id="ajaxContent" style="width:1024px;"></div>

    <div id='siteLoader'> 
    <div id='siteDetailLoader'> 
        <img src='ajax_loader.gif' border='0' /> 
            Please wait while the page loads...<br /> <br />
     </div>
</div>
```

This is the most used way to load asynchronous content in the web. But pay attention at this: The `http://kater.selfhost.me/stats/skins.php` page is made to open as single page in the web, so it has `<html>` , `<head>`, `<body>` , etc.. tags, so..after loading this page into another you'll have two `<html>`, `<body>` .. tags in a same page, this is bad, but modern browsers have an awesome common sense and don't bother by this, but you should know that, and be aware.

The actual problem why it isn't loading yet, is this javascript in your content:

```
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
EXref="";top.document.referrer?EXref=top.document.referrer:EXref=document.referrer;//-->
</script>
```

I removed that and now works fine. Remember that's a quick fix, I don't know what this JS does.

Why it works in `<iframe>` and doesn't via AJAX? When you open in `<iframe>` is like opening in a new browser window..and via AJAX, as I have said, it'll load the page content straight inside your "parent" page.

So, removing this Javascript will work, but awesome further solutions:

1. If you need to open this page both as content to load (via AJAX), both as single page, you can make two pages.. one for each need.
2. If you just want to use as content to load, remove `<html>`, `<head>`, etc.. tags, and fix Javascript to work inside another page.

Comment: Sorry! I forgot to remove "container" div  that hide entire content. Try again removing "containter" div, I have updated my answer, you can use my new code again.

Comment: i edited it: http://kater.selfhost.me/test/ have a look for yourself... somehow i think i am not seeing the clue why this just doesn't get the data from /stats/skins.php

Comment: I have updated my answer at the end, read that, you have a bit of Javascript that isn't working when loads, and I explained why it worked before with <iframe>. Remove this slice of code and try again.

Comment: ok i found this part of code... its within my php, it's a external tracking tool i used to monitor in the past and had it left in the code... dumb me but a big thanks for your answer! works fine!